# Stacking issue caused by CSS animation

Tags: css, wordpress, animation, position, z-index

I have a search area at the top of a homepage I am trying to build. The search area consists of one text input and two dropdown boxes, as well as a submit or "Search" button.

I have tried to add a fade in animation from animate.css to the Wordpress widget I am using, which worked. However the dropdown boxes are now overlapped by the container div below.

You can see the version with the animation added [**here**](http://dev-pantri.pantheonsite.io/)

and [**here**](http://test-pantri.pantheonsite.io/) is an older version without the animation, where the dropdown boxes appear as they should.

Does anyone know of any way of keeping the animation without affecting the stacking order, or a fix?

Thanks!

Some of the relevant source/styling code is shown below

```
<form class="job_search_form" action="http://dev-pantri.pantheonsite.io/profiles/" method="GET">

<div class="search_jobs">

    <div class="search_keywords">
        <label for="search_keywords">Keywords</label>
        <input type="text" name="search_keywords" id="search_keywords" placeholder="What are you looking for?" />
    </div>

    <div class="search_location">
        <label for="search_location">Location</label>
        <input type="text" name="search_location" id="search_location" placeholder="Location" />
    </div>


    <div class="search_categories">
        <label for="search_categories">Category</label>
        <select name='search_categories[]' id='search_categories' class='job-manager-category-dropdown '  data-placeholder='Choose a category&hellip;' data-no_results_text='No results match' data-multiple_text='Select Some Options'>
 <option value="">All categories</option>   
 <option class="level-0" value="44">Arts and Entertainment</option>
 <option class="level-1" value="53">Nightclubs</option>
 <option class="level-0" value="59">Bars</option>
 <option class="level-0" value="61">Lodging</option>
 <option class="level-1" value="62">Hotels</option>
 <option class="level-0" value="63">Nightlife</option>
 <option class="level-0" value="58">Outdoors</option>
 <option class="level-0" value="54">Restaurants</option>
</select>
    </div>


    <div class="filter_wide filter_by_tag">Filter by tag: <span class="filter_by_tag_cloud"></span></div><select  name='search_region' id='search_region' class='search_region' >
<option value='0'>All Regions</option>
<option class="level-0" value="55">Annex</option>
<option class="level-0" value="56">Beaconsfield Village</option>
<option class="level-0" value="57">Bloordale Village</option>
<option class="level-0" value="40">Casa Loma</option>
<option class="level-0" value="39">Corktown</option>
<option class="level-0" value="22">Downtown Core</option>
<option class="level-0" value="23">Dufferin Grove</option>
<option class="level-0" value="24">Entertainment District</option>
<option class="level-0" value="25">Fashion District</option>
<option class="level-0" value="21">Harbourfront</option>
<option class="level-0" value="20">Little Italy</option>
<option class="level-0" value="16">Parkdale</option>
<option class="level-0" value="15">Trinity Bellwoods</option>
```

```
<p class="filter-by-type-label">Filter by type:</p><input type="hidden" id="search_context" name="search_context" value="22" /> <ul class="job_types">
                <li><label for="job_type_freelance" class="freelance"><input type="checkbox" name="filter_job_type[]" value="freelance"  id="job_type_freelance" /> Freelance</label></li>
                <li><label for="job_type_full-time" class="full-time"><input type="checkbox" name="filter_job_type[]" value="full-time"  id="job_type_full-time" /> Full Time</label></li>
                <li><label for="job_type_internship" class="internship"><input type="checkbox" name="filter_job_type[]" value="internship"  id="job_type_internship" /> Internship</label></li>
                <li><label for="job_type_part-time" class="part-time"><input type="checkbox" name="filter_job_type[]" value="part-time"  id="job_type_part-time" /> Part Time</label></li>
                <li><label for="job_type_temporary" class="temporary"><input type="checkbox" name="filter_job_type[]" value="temporary"  id="job_type_temporary" /> Temporary</label></li>
        </ul>
<input type="hidden" name="filter_job_type[]" value="" />
<button type="submit" data-refresh="Loading..." data-label="Search" name="update_results" class="update_results">Search</button><div class="showing_jobs"></div></form>
```

CSS:

```
.animated {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}

.fadeInUp {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUp;
    animation-name: fadeInUp;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add a z-index to your search area container div.  Keep in mind z-index only works for positioned elements (absolute, relative, fixed). Using the animated version of your site I added an inline style through dev tools:

`style="position:relative; z-index:10"`

Which seemed to work - try it out in your CSS:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I had actually tried that over and over, wondering why it wasn't working and I was styling the wrong div. Thank you so much I was on the verge of pulling my hair out haha.

Comment: Ah, yeah, positions and z-index are really finicky, glad it works now though!